# How do you wait to receive one of several MessageQueue's in .NET?

Tags: .net, msmq, synchronous

I am porting an older C++ component to C#. It's job is to sit idle, until a message arrives on one of several queues, then deal with it.

In C++ we used WaitForMultipleObjects, passing it an array of handles to each of the queues we're monitoring.

In .NET, the MessageQueue class has a .Receive() method that blocks until the message arrives, but I do not see an obvious way to block until a message from any of several queues arrives.

Ideally I do not want to use the asynchronous API. This .NET program will be using some native libraries that are not thread safe.

Comment: Are the messages in the various queues the same?  Will the single receiver be able to process them?

Comment: pretty much, yeah. Each message just contains a guid.

Comment: MessageQueue has methods like BeginReceive.  Which returns an IAsyncResult.  Which has a AsynchWaitHandle property that you can pass WaitHandle.WaitAny().  All the same thing, just different names.

Comment: That sounds like just what I need. I'll try it out tomorrow.